# Logic for multiple phone number edit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form in my project where I need to save 4 phone numbers.***The text box for entering phone numbers are displayed on a button click.*** What I have to implement is as follows.

While adding--->

- Entered 1st PH.No
- On button click, displayed 2nd text box. Not wanted to enter the value.
- Clicked the button, displayed 3rd text box.
- Entered 3rd PH.NO.
- Saved the form with details.

While editing the same form I want as follows--->

- On button click ,show tex tbox for entering 2nd PH.No.
- Entered 2nd PH.No.
- On next button click show text box for entering 4th PH.No.

What actually happens is:

While editing, in UI instead of the click for the 4th PH.NO , the click for 3rd PH.No is happening(The textbox for 3rd PH.No is not displaying there but a lag of that click is happening there.) Since 3rd PH.No is already saved, I don't want to check it's count.

I used count to check this.

How can I solve this issue?

```
     count:this.props.patientInfo.WorkPhone?this.props.patientInfo.MobilePhone?this.props.patientInfo.RelativePhone? this.props.patientInfo.AltPhone1?4:3:2:1:0
         add(e){
         if(this.state.count > 4){
                    this.setState({
                        clickFlag:true,
                        count:0
                    })
                }
            else
            {   this.setState({
                    clickFlag:true,
                    count:this.state.count+1
                })}}
render()
{const inputs =[
            {'WorkPhone':patientInfo.WorkPhone?patientInfo.WorkPhone:'',
            'MobilePhone':patientInfo.MobilePhone?patientInfo.MobilePhone:'',
            'RelativePhone':patientInfo.RelativePhone?patientInfo.RelativePhone:'',
            'AltPhone1':patientInfo.AltPhone1?patientInfo.AltPhone1:'',
            'AltPhone2':patientInfo.AltPhone2?patientInfo.AltPhone2:'',
            'AltPhone3':patientInfo.AltPhone3?patientInfo.AltPhone3:'',
            'AltPhone4':patientInfo.AltPhone4?patientInfo.AltPhone4:'',
            'AltPhone5':patientInfo.AltPhone5?patientInfo.AltPhone5:''}
        ]
        return(
        <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row">
                                <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_key" title="Phone">
                                    Phone
                                </div>
                                <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_valuePhone">
                                    <Field name="HomePhone" onInput={this.onCheckInput} maxLength="10" 
                                    pattern="\d*" component="input" type="text" onChange={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Home")} placeholder="HomePhone" style={{"width":"117px"}} title={' Home Phone: ' + this.formatPhoneNumber(patientInfo.HomePhone)}/>

                                     {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && !patientDetailsForm.values.HomePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <Field name="HomePhoneDisabled" component={Checkbox} />
                                    }
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.HomePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled"
                                     onClick={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Home")}><div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled_label">X</div></div>
                                    }
                                    {!patientInfo.HomePhone || (!patientInfo.WorkPhone && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&& !patientDetailsForm.values.WorkPhone) || (!patientInfo.MobilePhone && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&&!patientDetailsForm.values.MobilePhone ) ||
                                    (!patientInfo.RelativePhone   && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&&!patientDetailsForm.values.RelativePhone)|| (!patientInfo.AltPhone1 && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&&!patientDetailsForm.values.AltPhone1)
                                    || (!patientInfo.AltPhone2 && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values &&!patientDetailsForm.values.AltPhone2)||(!patientInfo.AltPhone3 && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&&!patientDetailsForm.values.AltPhone3)|| 
                                    (!patientInfo.AltPhone4 && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && !patientDetailsForm.values.AltPhone4 )|| (!patientInfo.AltPhone5 && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values&&!patientDetailsForm.values.AltPhone5 )?
                                      <div>  <button title="add" className="dashboard-patients-details_addicn" onClick={this.add} style={{'cursor':'pointer',"marginLeft":"5px"}}>               
                                    <PhoneAdd/> </button>
                                     </div> :''
                                    }
                                </div>

                            </div>
     {this.state.clickFlag && this.state.count<=4?
     inputs && inputs.map((node,index) => 
           this.state.count=== 1 && !patientInfo.WorkPhone && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.WorkPhone.length<10 ?
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row">
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_key1"> </div>
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_valuePhone">
                                 <Field name="WorkPhone" component="input" onInput={this.onCheckInput} placeholder="WorkPhone"
                                     maxLength="10" type="text"  onChange={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Work")} />
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && !patientDetailsForm.values.WorkPhoneDisabled &&
                                        <Field name="WorkPhoneDisabled" component={Checkbox} />
                                    }
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.WorkPhoneDisabled &&
                                        <div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled"
                                     onClick={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Work")}><div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled_label">X</div></div>
                                    }  
                                 </div>
                                 </div> :
      this.state.count === 2 && !patientInfo.MobilePhone && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.MobilePhone.length<10 ?
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row">
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_key1"> </div>
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_valuePhone">
                                 <Field name="MobilePhone" maxLength="10" onInput={this.onCheckInput} placeholder="MobilePhone"
                                    component="input" type="text"  onChange={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Mobile")} />
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && !patientDetailsForm.values.MobilePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <Field name="MobilePhoneDisabled" component={Checkbox} />
                                    }
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.MobilePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled"
                                     onClick={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Mobile")}><div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled_label">X</div></div>
                                    } 
                                 </div>
                                 </div>:
     this.state.count === 3 && !patientInfo.RelativePhone && patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.RelativePhone.length<10?
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row">
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_key1"> </div>
                                 <div className="dashboard-patients-details_row_valuePhone">
                                 <Field name="RelativePhone" onInput={this.onCheckInput} maxLength="10" placeholder="RelativePhone"
                                     component="input" type="text"  onChange={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Relative")} />
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && !patientDetailsForm.values.RelativePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <Field name="RelativePhoneDisabled" component={Checkbox} />
                                    }
                                    {patientDetailsForm && patientDetailsForm.values && patientDetailsForm.values.RelativePhoneDisabled &&
                                        <div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled"
                                     onClick={()=> this.onEnablePhone("Relative")}><div className="dashboard-patients-details_phone-disabled_label">X</div></div>
                                    } 
                                 </div>
                                 </div>:................................)
}
```

This is my code

Comment: Plz add some code

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xv33mw053z check this.

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan okay, I'll add

Comment: @SyedMehtabHassan I added some of my code.Please check it and help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so you can use another approach to handle this problem. If I understand your problem correctly here's the solution forms:

Assumption: For each form

1- Make a state for inputs;

```
this.state={
            WorkPhone: patientInfo.WorkPhone?patientInfo.WorkPhone:'',
            MobilePhone: patientInfo.MobilePhone?patientInfo.MobilePhone:'',
            RelativePhone: patientInfo.RelativePhone?patientInfo.RelativePhone:'',
            AltPhone1: patientInfo.AltPhone1?patientInfo.AltPhone1:'',
            AltPhone2: patientInfo.AltPhone2?patientInfo.AltPhone2:'',
            AltPhone3: patientInfo.AltPhone3?patientInfo.AltPhone3:'',
            AltPhone4: patientInfo.AltPhone4?patientInfo.AltPhone4:'',
            AltPhone5: patientInfo.AltPhone5?patientInfo.AltPhone5:''
            }
```

2- Then associate inputs with these possible values(I highly recommend that you use a component library or make your code readable than this) using `antd forms`:

```
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator(`WorkPhone`)(
      <Input placeholder="Phone Number" style={{ width: '60%', marginRight: 8 }} />
    )}
  </Form.Item>
<Form.Item>
    {getFieldDecorator(`WorkPhone`)(
      <Input placeholder="Phone Number" style={{ width: '60%', marginRight: 8 }} />
        )}
</Form.Item>
// continue for all phone numbers in state
```

now when you submit and follow [antd forms](https://ant.design/components/form/) documentation you can end up checking which of phone numbers are given and which not in order to show that field.

3- you can get an idea by using the function of this sort

```
add = () => {
  const { form } = this.props;
  const keys = form.getFieldValue('keys');
  const nextKeys = keys.concat(id++);
  form.setFieldsValue({
    keys: nextKeys,
  });
}
```

P.S: [This](https://codesandbox.io/s/xv33mw053z) is a nice example to follow as mentioned by @Dhaval,

Comment: How can I implement 3rd step using normal Html like Field tag?

Comment: The third step is only a function to add the field, which we know exists in our state. You can do something like; check which one of the states are filled and which ones are not to show the next field. Does it make sense?

Comment: I did like that. But as I said some logical mistakes occurs like if the phonenumber3 value is already given before, the count is run on background but the user thinks it just a fault.